# find_or_initialize_by doesn't work with 2 columns

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to insert data in my database using ActiveRecord.

When I use `pdays = MyModel.new` for initialization rather then the below `find_or_initialize_by`, the script runs fine. But it ONLY runs once. I need this to run daily to perform updates. When I try running the script the second time with `pdays = MyModel.new`, then no duplicate key constraint is raised.

Hence I am trying the below find_or_initialize_by with 2 arguments, but that gives an error:

> undefined method `find_or_initialize_by'

2 columns together make the unique record:

```
vertica_traffic.each do |vdays|

  pdays = MyModel.find_or_initialize_by([:local_dt], vdays[:community_id])

  pdays[:local_date]       = vdays_traffic[:local_d]
  pdays[:community_id]     = vdays_traffic[:community_id]
  pdays[:uniquesters]      = vdays_traffic[:uniques]

  pdays.save

end
```

Comment: are you using rails 3.2.x?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could try:

```
MyModel.find_or_initialize_by_local_dt_and_comunity_id([:local_dt], vdays[:community_id])
```

appending the columns names by with an `_and_`

Comment: Please note, if anyone sees this answer in 2016 - That this method is deprecated in Rails 4+.

Comment: Yes find_or_initialize with appending columns using _and_ is deprecated but you can use it like this way: MyModel.find_or_initialize_by(local_dt: [:local_dt], community_id: vdays[:community_id])

Answer (score 9):

If you are using rails 3.2.1 and above, the new name of the method is `first_or_initialize`.  It is used with conjunction with `where`.  In your case, since you are calling save, you should use `first_or_create` but if you want to manually call `save`, just replace the method and call save after

```
MyModel.where(local_date: vdays_traffic[:local_date], community_id: vdays_traffic[:community_id]).first_or_create do |record|
  record.uniquesters = vdays_traffic[:uniques]
end
```

Answer (score 9):

[I read here that in Rails 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22472584/rails4-deprecation-warning-for-find-or-initialize-by-method), this is the correct syntax:

```
Progress.find_or_initialize_by(chore_id: chore.id, period: period[chore.frequency], account_id: chore.account_id)
```