# Rails4 Deprecation warning for find_or_initialize_by method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am upgrading to Rails4 from 3.2. I have the following query:

```
progress = Progress.find_or_initialize_by_chore_id_and_period_and_account_id(chore.id, period[chore.frequency], chore.account_id)
```

While running test, I am getting deprecation warning

```
DEPRECATION WARNING: This dynamic method is deprecated. Please use e.g. Post.find_or_initialize_by(name: 'foo') instead. (called from bump_progress at /Users/newimac/RailsApp/bank/app/models/child.rb:200)
```

So, I have updated my query as follows:

```
progress = Progress.where('chore.id' => 'chore_id', 'period[chore.frequency]' => 'period', 'chore.account_id' => 'account_id').first_or_initialize
```

But its not working. Is my query correct ?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can use the following:

```
Progress.find_or_initialize_by(chore_id: chore.id, period: period[chore.frequency], account_id: chore.account_id)
```

Answer (score 14):

```
# find_or_initialize_by_
# Rails 3: 
Team.find_or_initialize_by_name('Justice League')
# Rails 4: 
Team.find_or_initialize_by(name: 'Justice League')
# or
Team.where(name: 'Justice League').first_or_initialize
```

NB: In these cases, the word 'initialize' will be like calling `Team.new`. You can also replace 'initialize' 'create' to instead call `Team.create`, like this: `.find_or_create_by` or `.first_or_create`

Expanded and improved, but based on: http://blog.remarkablelabs.com/2012/12/what-s-new-in-active-record-rails-4-countdown-to-2013