# Rails bulk insert in multiple tables

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv

I have the following scenario: I have some CSVs to be imported in a Rails application and the size of the dataset can be over 100k rows and this implies a huge amount of memory in use - which I don't have on the server.

Each CSV represent a table dump.
Now, my problem is that I need to import the data in several tables maintaining the relationships by foreign keys.

What I've done so far is roughly this:

- Create ids cache hashes
- For each CSV/table `find_or_initialize` by an attribute where possible, or perform something like `model.where({complicated conditions}) || model.create({complicated conditions})` saving the created object
- Populate the ids cache mapping `CSV id` => `DB id`

In the `complicated conditions` statement can sits some of the ids saved in previous tables and cached.

Have a look [at the code here](https://github.com/linguisticexplorer/Linguistic-Explorer/blob/master/lib/group_data/importer.rb) for more details.

Note: what I need is more an `upsert` rather than just a plain `insert`.

Some optimisations I've already tried:

- Used transactions => less memory used and quicker to insert
- Used [`crewait` gem](https://github.com/theAlmanac/crewait) => Quicker than plain AR, but slower than transactions
- `model.skip_callbacks(:create)` => speedup or memory improvement not noticeable
- Cached the `user` model which is widely used in all the other tables => high memory use and slower (?!)
- In case a row is already present, select only the `id` attribute to use less memory => not a big difference in speed/memory
- Optimised hash structure for cache: used [Google Hashes](https://github.com/rdp/google_hash) structures to store ids as INT->INT => 10% less memory use

Something else I've looked at but cannot figure out how to use:

- Single and long SQL query: it is basically the idea behind `crewait` but it doesn't work great as far as I tried
- [`activerecord-import`](https://github.com/zdennis/activerecord-import): it's faster to import, but I'll then lose all the relationships or CSV to DB id mapping
- [`upsert`](https://github.com/seamusabshere/upsert): I've seen it but I would like to use it as last resort (it's a bit tricky IMHO).

Any suggestion, recommendation on how to improve is very welcome: talking about tool, library, strategy or whatever.

Update

This is a simplified example of the CSVs I have:

**lings.csv**

```
------------------------
| id | name    | depth |
------------------------
| 0  | English |   0   |
------------------------
| 1  | French  |   0   |
------------------------
| etc..                |
------------------------
```

**properties.csv**

```
-----------------------------------
| id | name         | description |
-----------------------------------
| 0  | Subject_Verb | bla, bla... |
-----------------------------------
| 1  | Verb_Subject | bla, bla... |
-----------------------------------
| etc..                           |
-----------------------------------
```

**lings_properties.csv**

```
--------------------------------------
| id | value | ling_id | property_id |
--------------------------------------
| 0  | Yes   |    0    |     0       |
--------------------------------------
| 1  | No    |    1    |     1       |
--------------------------------------
| etc..                              |
--------------------------------------
```

Looking at the example above, when I import the Lings and Properties different ids will be assigned to them but I still want the LingsProperties to be linked to English and French thought.
I cannot use the CSV ids in the DB - they are assigned by another application that has a different schema from the one I'm importing them in.

#### Update 2

My Rails version is 3.0.20.
I'm moving on Rails 3.2 (or later) where I can use `first_or_create` (or similar) but for the moment I'm in stuck with Rails 3.0.

Comment: are the `foreign_keys` not in the table already??? if they are then all you need to do is to something similar to `LOAD DATA INFILE 'path/to/file.csv' INTO TABLE your_table FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'` in `MySQL`, then to save memory, reading the file with `File.open` directly and parsing the csv yourself would save you a lot of memory over using the ruby `CSV` library

Comment: Unfortunately they can be either in the DB or not, but I don't know it before hand. Basically the application can handle multiple datasets while the CSVs are representing a single dataset (most of the time): when importing I can either update an existing one or uploading a branch new one.

Comment: if you don't know beforehand, then how do you intend to set up the relationship???

Comment: Perhaps I've expressed it in the wrong way. What I mean is that the relationship in the CSV is expressed by foreign keys defined in the CSV: in one CSV I have an id for a Ling and in another CSV I've got a Value linked to that Ling through a `ling_id`. Now, when I'm importing all the CSV I would like to save the Value maintaining the relationship with the Ling instance above whether that particular instance exists already or not in the DB - that's why I run an `find_or_initialize` query to import.

Comment: Just import the CSV's into the DB via `MySQL` prompt, it would figure out the relationships by itself, if the CSV already contains the foreign keys as you have described

Comment: If I use the `MySQL` prompt then I'll use an `auto_increment` settings for the ids: at that point won't I lose all the relationships?

Comment: you probably want to read [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html) but I think `MySQL` `LOAD DATA` would not generate new `ids` but use the existing ones from the `csv` files

Comment: I cannot use the CSV ids because they come from a different DB and they could be already assigned to store other rows - which potentially belong to a different dataset. That's why I haven't taken that route before. I'll update the question with some more information about the CSV format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually I'm managed to keep the same code structure and find a solution that fits my particular scenario.

Unfortunately with Rails 3.0 I didn't have so many choices, so I've just come up with the following pattern:

```
model.class.skip_callback(:create)
model.class.transaction do
  CSV.foreach(file_path, :headers => true) do |row|
    // unfortunately this bit here has to be customised on the model
    // so append after the _by_ all the conditions you are looking for
    item = model.class.find_or_initialize_by_this_and_that(this, that, ...) do |m|
      m.more = row["more"]
    end


    item.save!(:validate => false)

    ids_cache[row["id"]] = item.id

  end
end
model.class.set_callback(:create)
```

Downside of the solution above: you have to tailoring the `find_or_initialize_by` method for each model, but with that I've managed to remove the GoogleHash structures, and the profiler shows a drop of half of the memory used during the process.
Even in time terms, it is quite good, with a smaller speed-up (~10%) compared to the previous codebase.

The validation disabled on save helps a lot (~80% from my tests) to pull down the memory usage, together with the `find_or_initialize_by` method (~20%) - which I didn't know (ops...) [could take multiple arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15363329/find-or-initialize-by-doesnt-work-with-2-columns).

I bet you can use something like `find_or_initialize_by` also in Rails 3.2, even more elegant:

```
model.class.where(complicated_conditions).first_or_create(complicated_conditions)
```

This last one hasn't tested yet, but as soon as I'll test it will try to come back to write it up.

**Note**: validate the CSV data before using this, basically all the checks are disabled on this side so preprocess the files before passing it to the importer!

Answer (score 0):

Since you asked for suggestions, I'll give one, but with no warranty expressed or implied.

I think it might be faster and it certainly will be less memory intensive to insert all the records with the wrong foreign keys in one pass while building the ID maps simultaneously (as you are doing).  Note you can send a batch of multiple records to the server using `create` with a list argument. This might have an advantage by decreasing locking overhead.

Then use `update_all` calls to substitute the good (new) foreign keys for the bad (old) ones.  Something like:

```
PropertyOwnership.where(:ling_id => old_id).update_all('ling_id = ?', new_id)
```

With this you are taking Active Record ORM mostly out of the processing loop, which ought to help.  The only memory overhead should be the integer -> integer id maps.

To keep the old ids from colliding with new ones, just increment the foreign key fields read from the CSV by a number larger than current max id in the table plus its size.  This ought to keep it out of the range of fresh id's created during the inserts.

The reason this should be faster is that the `update_all` calls will occur entirely on the server side in a single table, whereas `find_or_initialize` is doing a select followed by insert or update later when you save, and the accesses are occurring in depth first order across tables.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I've thought about this before, but because it would require a bit of more of refactoring and rearranging of the codebase I was trying all the other options before. In case of no other solutions I will give it definitely a try!